# eval() function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

im trying to convert a json string from my .php file using eval() function but it doesnt work. the browser console says
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'...

but when i comment out the line where eval() is, and use document.write(data); the string appears...

here's my code..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var go = function() {

        $.get("testjson.php", function(data) {

            var obj = eval("(" + data + ")");

            document.write(obj.name + "<br />");
            document.write(obj.date + "<br />");
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' value='go' onclick='go()' />
<body>
</html>
```

and here's the code of my testjson.php file...

```
<?php

    $msg = array(
        "name"=>"hi there Victor!",
        "date"=>"Monday 21st Feb 2010"
    );

    $myMsg = json_encode($msg);

    echo $myMsg;

?>
```

im using latest version of jquery..

Comment: Don't do eval. There's much better ways to get the data as JSON like e.g. setting correct content-type (or using `$.getJSON`)

Comment: Your script works. You sure you're loading this off a webserver and not as `file:///`?

Comment: Did you leave the question or are you not aware that you can respond to comments here?

Comment: sorry i was trying to fix the problem... i'm using a webserver...

Comment: Could you update your post with the 'exact' code then from your testjson.php? As it sounds like more than just a json string is being passed out of that php file (which can cause the json parser in js to fail).

Answer (score 0):

There are other suggestions in the comments and answers here about using `$.getJSON()` instead of `eval()`, or specifying `json` as a parameter in `$.get()`, and these are all good suggestions.  But, they aren't the reason this isn't working.

Simply, you're missing a semi-colon in your `var go = ....` function definition after the closing brace near the bottom.

Comment: randall.. i tried your code.. but still it didn't work... @nick i already put a semi-colon but nothing has changed..

Comment: Are you sure the code that you're trying is the code you posted in your question? I tried the code as you wrote it, added the semi-colon, and it works as expected for me.

Comment: With or without the semicolon, the code will work fine, so its not the reason he is getting an error about a "<" (which sounds like output corruption from his php).

Comment: the code is now fixed! lol i don't know why, but i just removed the commented html code under my .php code... how the heck it affects my code in the first place?? it's just a comment... :/ 

by just having <!-- --> below the ?> line, the code won't work anymore.. what the heck?

Comment: @Randall You're right. As a matter of good coding practices, I'm accustomed to closing all of my lines in JS with a semi-colon, even if it's the last line and not necessary. So when I copied and pasted his code, added the semi-colon, and successfully tested the code, I mistakenly assumed that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

the code is now fixed! lol i don't know why, but i just removed the commented html code under my .php code... how the heck it affects my code in the first place?? it's just a comment... :/

Comment: Comment html code is still html code. Assuming you were using html comments of the like `<!-- ... lots of html here... -->`. This is because json comes in and goes "what is this '<' ?!" and bails. If you have the html behind PHP comments, then thats a different story.